# My validation is preventing other things from uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

In my app a user can upload a picture(with paperclip) or a link from youtube. The link is able to be submitted but now when I try to upload a picture I get a validation error saying the link is invalid. I have been going after this for like an hour now and I'm just going in circles at this point, any help would be awesome.

post.rb

```
class Post< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  YT_LINK_FORMAT = /\A.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*\z/i
  validates :link, allow_nil: true, format: YT_LINK_FORMAT
  before_create :set_content_type

  has_attached_file :pic, :styles => { :thumb => "600x600#", :medium => "300x300#", :small => "160x160#"}

  validates_attachment_content_type :pic, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png" ]

  def set_content_type
    self.is_pic = !self.pic_file_name.nil?
    self.is_link = !self.link.nil?
    # parse link
    if self.is_link
      uid = link.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)
      self.uid = uid[2] if uid && uid[2]
      if self.uid.to_s.length != 11
        self.errors.add(:link, 'is invalid.')
        false
      elsif Post.where(uid: self.uid).any?
        self.errors.add(:link, 'is not unique.')
        false
      else
        get_additional_info
      end
    end
  end
```

Post_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post= Post.create(post_params) do |post|
    post.is_pic = true if params[:post][:pic]
    post.is_link = true if params[:post][:link]
  end
  @post.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post}
    else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The form

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="uploads">
    <h3>Upload Photo</h3>
  <div class="visible-xs">
  <%= f.file_field :pic %>
    <h3>YouTube Link</h3>
  <div class="visible-xs">
    <%= f.label :link %>
    <%= f.text_field :link, required: false %>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-info" %>
  </div>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: have you tried `allow_blank: true`? from what I have seen params are passed as empty strings not true nil values. So `allow_nil` is not having an impact here where as `allow_blank` should pass validation.

Comment: Yes. I get the same result.

Comment: Is a link being passed with the image? If so then it must be a link that passes that regex. If not then it should not validate it.

Comment: It shouldn't but it is for some reason.

Comment: Did you create a few test objects before adding the validation? It sounds like you have invalid records already in your database. So, when you try to update, it shows an error. You could remove all Posts or clean up the existing data.

Comment: I was able to upload images before I added the validation